# Printing My Vector Doesn't Work (No Compiler Errors)

Tags: c++, vector

## **What I must make:**

A program that makes a double vector with at least 30 negative and positive elements. I also must have functions to calculate/print the standard deviation, the mean value, the highest value, and the lowest value of the vector. Next, I will need a `split()` function to split the values of the double vector into 2 new double vectors, `positive` and `negative` (the former will have all values from 0 - max_positive_value, the latter will have all nonzero negative values). Finally, I need one last function to display both of the modified vectors.

## **My Issue:**

***Nothing*** whatsoever is being printed from my `split()` function! For debugging purposes, I made it so that it prints all the values of the positive and negative vectors, but it prints nothing. The compiler makes no mention of any error of any kind, which doesn't really help!

## Code Block in Question:

```
double split(const vector<double> &data)
{
    vector <double> positive;
    vector <double> negative;
    int j = 0; // iterate inner

    // add to pos/neg vector depending on value of data[i]
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {

        if (data[i] >= 0)
        {
            positive[j] = data[i];
            j++;

        } else if (data[i] < 0)
        {
            negative[j] = data[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    // debugging, print vectors
    for (int vC = 0; vC < positive.size(); ++vC)
    {
        cout << positive[vC] << endl;
    }

    for (int vC = 0; vC < negative.size(); ++vC)
    {
        cout << positive[vC] << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

## Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime> // both this and the next header are needed for
#include <cstdlib> // rand() to randomly generate numbers 
#include <cmath> // sqrt

using namespace std;

// passing by reference uses less resources
double split(const vector<double> &data)
{
    vector <double> positive;
    vector <double> negative;
    int j = 0; // iterate inner

    // add to pos/neg vector depending on value of data[i]
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {

        if (data[i] >= 0)
        {
            positive[j] = data[i];
            j++;

        } else if (data[i] < 0)
        {
            negative[j] = data[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    // debugging
    for (int vC = 0; vC < positive.size(); ++vC)
    {
        cout << positive[vC] << endl;
    }

    for (int vC = 0; vC < negative.size(); ++vC)
    {
        cout << positive[vC] << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}

// calculate std deviation
double calculateSD(const vector<double> &data)
{
    // calculate sum of data
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        sum += data[i]; 

    // calculate average
    double avg = sum / data.size();
 
    // calculate and return the standard deviation
    double stdDev = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        stdDev += (data[i] - avg) * (data[i] - avg);
    return sqrt(stdDev / data.size());
}



int main()
{
    // vector with minimum 30 values
    vector <double> data (30);

    // seed rand() with time
    srand (time(NULL));
    
    // fill vector with neg/pos num
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        data[i] = rand() - (RAND_MAX / 2);
        // cout << data[i] << endl;
    }

    split(data);

}
```

**NOTE:** I have not implemented the needed highest/lowest/mean functions, yet.

Comment: Print out the `data.size()` to make sure you're not getting a nasty surprise.

Comment: Also look up whatever your development tools use for a debugger, learn the basics of how to use it, and then fire the sucker up ansd start stepping theough the code. It really helps to see exactly what the conmputer's doing as it does it. Breaks a lot of ego, but totally wirth it for the productivity boost.

Comment: Your vectors `positive` and `negative` are default initialized, so they contain zero elements. So writing something like `positive[j] = data[i]` is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at). You can use `push_back` to add elements to the end of a vector, or you can initialize the vectors to contain `data.size()` many `0`s` if you want the indices of the `positive` and `negative` vectors to match up with the indices of the original `data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your vectors

```
vector <double> positive;
vector <double> negative;
```

are empty, so accessing their elements is undefined behavior. You need

```
if (data[i] >= 0)
{
    positive.push_back(data[i]);
} else if (data[i] < 0)
{
    negative.push_back( data[i]);          
}
```